# How to get the path in file of a different file of the module?

Tags: module, path, package, raku

How do I get the path of another file of the module?

I tried it this way but I don't know where to get the `$here` and I don't know if it would work if I had the `$here`?

```
use v6;
unit class Aaa::Bbb::Ccc;

my $here = '.../lib/Aaa/Bbb/Ccc.rakumod'.IO;
my $bin = $here.parent.parent.parent.add( 'bin' ).add( 'app' );

use Pod::Load;
my $pod = load( $bin );
# use the $pod
```

When I try this, `$pod` is empty:

```
use Pod::Load;
my $pod = load( $*PROGRAM );
say $pod.raku;  # $[]
```

Comment: The three dots are only a placeholder, the don't mean anything else.

Comment: In this case you can access directly the pod of the program itself, it should be in $=pod.

Comment: jjmerelo: according to the documentation, this only works if the pod is in the current file.

Comment: that's correct but in your first example I had the impression that it was a single file. Are they two different files?

Comment: jjmerelo: I fixed the example.

Comment: anyway, there's no pod content in the example files you show here, to $pod is empty is correct, far as I see it.

Comment: The pod is in the `bin/app` file.

Comment: Ah, OK. Could be a Pod::Load issue... I'd need to see all the files to check that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "another file of the module". A module would represent only a single file; a distribution represent multiple modules and thus multiple files. Additionally a module cannot assume it is being loaded from a file system -- it might be loaded into memory out of a [tar file](https://github.com/ugexe/Raku-CompUnit--Repository--Tar) or [socket](https://github.com/ugexe/Raku-CompUnit--Repository--Github), and if a module were to try to access e.g. `"../MyOtherModule.rakumod".IO` it would obviously fail.

What you *can* safely do is get at the content of any module in the same distribution:

```
unit class Aaa::Bbb::Ccc;

my $bin-code = $?DISTRIBUTION.content("bin/app").open.slurp;
```

Comment: I tried it but it dies with this message: `Variable '$?DISTRIBUTION' is not declared. Did you mean 'Distribution'?`

Comment: You will need a rakudo version `2019.03` or newer.

Comment: The rakudo star downloads hosted on rakudo.org are currently not available.

Answer (score 1):

*Update:*
As @ugexe pointed out, if you intend on installing your module this will not work.

---

$?DISTRIBUTION seems like a good solution.

Otherwise an alternative is to use the $?FILE variable.  You would need to export this from your module if want to use it somewhere else in your program:

```
unit module MyModule;

our sub myDIR() {
    $?FILE.IO.dirname;
}
```

```
use MyModule;
myDIR()~"/relative/path/to/somefile
```

Comment: This does not work for installed modules. Do NOT recommend people to do this.